# Merge tag "misbehavior" into existing tag "behavior"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We've had the tag "behavior" for a long time. I'm now seeing the tag "misbehavior" too, and I feel it would make sense to have that as a synonym for "behavior" - or possibly for "discipline"?

Answer (score 1):

I think that a parent looking for help with misbehavior (like child-hurting other children) is going to not find what they are looking for when find all general behaviors (like burping, or wearing pink).  It waters down finding the particular area when that area is important to find.

The value proposition of the site is to help folks looking for insight or solutions to their problems.  The words used should be selected to maximize how quickly and effectively that happens.

I recommend that we keep both tags.