# How to handle misbehavior?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is about [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior).

It's based on an answer to [Merge tag "misbehavior" into existing tag "behavior"](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/950/30519) but I decided to turn it into its own question. I thought about it and believe that merging is not possible. But let's review the case first:

Tag wiki excerpts:

[behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior)

> Why do children act the way they do? Use [discipline] for questions about enforcing your rules.

[misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior)

> Questions regarding analyzing the reasoning behind a child's misbehavior. See the "discipline" tag for consequences of misbehavior.

Basically, [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior) is [behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior)'s evil twin.

There are currently 70 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior) tagged [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior) and when you have a look at them, you notice how often it was misused. The questions are not about "analyzing the reasoning" but about how to deal with misbehavior. However, the tag is not necessary for this purpose, since that's already covered by [discipline](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discipline).

Since there are so many questions tagged [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior) and it was misused so often, I came to the conclusion that merging is the wrong approach ([behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) makes no sense for most of these questions). There are too many nuances to consider. (For sure, it's possible that there weren't too many [misbhevaior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbhevaior) questions when the merging was suggested).

Here is a rare [exception](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/34091/30519), tagged [behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior). And another [one](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/29140/30519), with the same set of tags.

It seems that if [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior) was removed where wrongly used, not much would be left - including a reason to keep [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior).

But I do not want to blame the OPs, since it's quite intuitive to (mis)use that tag - your child misbehaves, so you tag it like that. And most parents prefer making the misbehavior stop to analyzing it. On the other hand, [behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) is so abstract, that the correct usage follows more intuitively.

Unless [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior) gets a new meaning (and the tag wiki excerpt is changed), it seems to be pretty useless. But even then it may be too broad and more specific tags (like the already existing [violence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/violence), [tantrums](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tantrums) etc.) may be useful or should be created.

**How to handle** [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior)**?**

Keep it, and if we do, then what should [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior) become? The way it is now, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I wrote a new question because I'm hoping for a more open discussion about what to do with *misbehavior*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea of making behavior the master. Misbehavior is just one kind of behavior, granting that it's a very broad one. There's good behavior, civil behavior, altruistic behavior, prosocial/antisocial behavior, etc... It's exactly as you concluded, the 'behavior' description can include directions to use discipline if that's what the OP wants to address. But sometimes people just want to know why their kids do the crazy stuff they do.

So

> **How to handle** [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior)**?**

Do away with this! Wouldn't it be wonderful if it were so easy in real life?

<sub>Just tonight my son was freaking out that his toddler was crossing her eyes on purpose and asked me if this was something he should be worried about. I'd call that a "behavioral issue", not a neurological one.</sub>